# chrome.contextMenus.create freezes chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contextmenu

I'm using event page!! and need to create context menu with sub-menus (deep tree).
How deep it is depends on users data. And creation of that context menu can be very frequent, because it depends on users actions. I can lower the frequency of those updates with some logic, but still, it can happen couple of times during session.
Problem is that creation of those menus is freezing Chrome for sec or two.
Since I'm using event page, I must use `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener`. Before, when I used onClick handler, I didn't experienced freezing (same amount of data).
Now I have to put sub menus creation in callback of my main context item (any other method?).

this is how I did it:

```
function createMenu(data) {
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {  
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            id: "v7",
            title : "some title",
            type : "normal",
            contexts : ["editable"],
        }, function() { 
            function buildTree(NTF, parID) {
                for (var i=0, l=NTF.length; i<l; i++) {
                    var menuId = NTF[i].id;
                    var menuText = NTF[i].text;
                    chrome.contextMenus.create({
                        id: menuId,
                        parentId: parID,
                        title: menuText,
                        type: "normal",
                        contexts: ["editable"],

                    });
                    if (NTF[i].children) buildTree(NTF[i].children, menuId);
                }
            }
            buildTree(data, 'v7');      
        });
    });
}
```

and this is my click handeler

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId.indexOf("id_pattern_of_my_submenu_items") > -1) {
        //do some stuff with it 
    }
});
```

Is there any better way to make this work without freezing the chrome?
My data array contains about 700 nodes, with max 3 lvl depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened a bug report at https://crbug.com/486505. The issue is caused by the fact that an event page performs a relatively expensive I/O operation (write to disk) when you add, modify or remove a context menu item in an event page.

Currently, the only work-around is to use a background page instead of an event page.